# Why is the condition in this simple program ignored when a comment is present?

Tags: c++

This simple program should clearly print nothing:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // the condition below is ignored! \\
    if (false)
        std::cout << "hello, world\n";
}
```

However, compiling it prints `hello, world` (followed by a newline) with all compilers I tried it with (gcc, clang, Sun CC, xlC). When removing the comment, the program behaves as expected, i.e., the program doesn't print anything.

**Why is the condition (always `false`) ignored with the comment present?**

Comment: Delete the `\\ ` comment. It makes next line `if(false)` ignored

Comment: You don't and as far as I know can't close single line comments

Comment: I would be interested in the reason for downvotes to improve the question. In case the suspicion is that the program doesn't behave as I claimed: it does (at least, with any conforming compiler).

Comment: Either the person asking the question knew that the comment was relevant or didn't. Either way, it's a bad question. If they didn't know it was relevant, they should have removed it. If they did, why ask the question without mentioning it? This is an *awful* question.

Comment: gcc/clang give correct warning *"warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]"*. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c95244afb5abbbf)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's the perfect setup for a self-answered question, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I guess he just wanted to present a puzzle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `\\` is escaping the newline and is making the `if (false)` part of the comment.

As an explanation, the `\` character at the end of a line in your c++ code signifies to the preprocessor that the next line is to be considered a continuation of the previous line. Because of this, `\` is sometimes called the line continuation character. This often comes in handy for multi-line #defines.

```
#define MY_LONG_MACRO \
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) \
    { std::cout << "multi-line macro"; }
```

Comment: @DietmarKühl thanks for your comment. I could have sworn that I have done that in the past, but I just tried it now with g++ and the space did not work. I have edited my answer.

Comment: the phase 1 is an implementation defined mapping according to 2.2 [lex.phases] paragraph 1. Apparently, gcc documents this odd behavior somewhere (although so far I haven't found where).

Comment: @DietmarKühl FWIW ISO/IEC 14882:2003 states "Each instance of a new-line character and an immediately preceding backslash character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines."

Comment: yes. However, phase 1 translation says that the mapping of source characters is implementation defined. I *guess* gcc (and others) probably defined that translation to allow spaces between a backslash and a newline to be ignored to copy with end of line sequence, like `\r\n` working on all systems.

Answer (score 2):

A single `\` is a line-continuation character indicating the next line is part of this line. It does not matter how many `\` there are, only the last one makes the next line part of the first line, the `\` before are just a part of the comment.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9a94327fd3b4f4)

Answer (score 0):

that is because `\` at the very end of line (no character even white spaces) is followed by means that next line is considered to be the completion of this one.

this generally used with strings eg:

```
string s = "sdgfdgfdgfdg\
       dssdfsdf";
```

if there's a white space after the single backslash above then you'll get a compile-time error.

you can add white space after it and everything will be ok eg:

```
// the condition below is ignored! \\[white space]
if (false)
    std::cout << "hello, world\n";
```

Comment: With gcc, clang, and xlC adding whitespace doesn't help. With Sun CC it does help.